# PowerShell Populate multi value attribute and convert case

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes, custom-attributes

I've tried to search but could not find anything whcih is not a surprise as I don't think what we're trying to do is so common.

I have a script that gathers a AD users according to filter together with custom attributes properties, we use a custom extended schema, and their values.

I do have an attribute called smtpHistory where an history of SMTP assigned to user are stored, I need to add what's in the $_.email attribute as the primary SMTP address (with SMTP in uppercase) while convertting any existing entry in lower case.

What I am doing right now is similar to

```
$mailHistory = $_.smtpHistory
$lowerMailHistory = $mailHistory.tolower()
# Insert all existing addresses in lowercase to the history attribute
Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -add @{ smtpHistory= $lowerMailHistory }
            $newMail = $_.mail

        # Append new default email address to smtpHistory
        #Set-ADUser $_.SamAccountNAme -Add @{ smtpHistory= "SMTP:$newMail" }
```

Technically speaking the above works but when I check the smtpHistory attribute what I get is multiple values on a single line like

```
smtp:test7@gmail.com smtp:test6@gmail.com
```

Instead of one value per line like

```
smtp:test7@gmail.com 
smtp:test6@gmail.com
```

The way I'm cycling through the users is via

```
$usersProxyAddress | ForEach-Object { ...
```

As using a foreach ($a in $usersProxyAddress ) is yielding the DN of each user and I cannot access the single properties (probably my fault).

Probably this is something silly that I'm overlooking but I cannot find a solution to the issue and any pointer/help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Dan.

Comment: How is the `smtpHistory` attribute schema defined? Is it properly defined as a multi-valued attribute?

Comment: Attribute is defined as Multi-valued yep. So far it was easy as the attribute was populated via a CSV file which was exported by Google apps provider, now we need to gather hthe value from the mail attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
try something like this
$mailHistory = $_.smtpHistory -join ';'
$mHistory = $mailHistory -spilt ";"
foreach($mH in $mHisotry)
{
  #yourcode
}
```

*"Need to be tested as i dont have domain controller available with me now."*

Comment: How come you don't have a DC lying around I always bring one with me ;-)

On a more serious note I'm going to test this and let you know, I really appreciate your help for now.

Comment: Hmm I guess I'm a step closer I still cannot find a way to convert the whole text in $mailhistory to lower.

If I do use the tolower() method all ends up on a single line, like in my original issue, same happens if I use

$mailhistory = $mailHistory -replace  'SMTP:','smtp:'

O^ve been spending so much time on this that I feel like I'm going in circles which is probably the case.